# SHOW CREATE TABLE statement only returning the create table statement

Tags: mysql

I have to transfer a bunch of mysql tables to different databases on a different server. To recreate the tables, I'm working with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in my code.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` always returns 2 columns, the table name and the SQL for creating the table.

Is it possible to formulate a Query that only returns a single column with the SQL for creating the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in using the show create table, you can use the following sql + linux cmds

```
mysql -uroot -p -Nsr -e 'SHOW CREATE TABLE schema.table_name\G'| tail -n +3 >> /tmp/ddl.sql
```

- this will pipe the output into a file of your choice.
- it will only put the create table sql syntax in.

ohh , if you have more then one table you can generate the command using concat and some info tables.

Comment: I don't have the option of using Linux Commands, as I'm accessing mysql through .NET connector. Obviously, I can parse the results of my query to an appropriate string, but a Query returning a single field would be preferable in regards to my design.